# DB connection error while installing Wordpress in a local easyphp server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I am trying to get a local server to test Wordpress, so I have installed easyphp Devserver 17.0 in my PC (Windows OS),

I have downloaded Wordpress code from Wordpress.org, paste it in `\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www` and followed step by step Wordpress installation instructions `(https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Famous_5-Minute_Install).`

**Problem is:**
when I access to my localhost server and wordpress folder, it starts wordpress installation and it ask for my database info (name, user, pass, host...) and I use "120.0.0.1" or "localhost" (my DB sever according to phpMyAdmin) as host, wordpress shows a `failed-to-connect-to-DB error`.

I've tried to use add DB Server port to host (127.0.0.1:3306), checked my http and DB servers are working, checked the other data is all correct and the answer is still the same.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by changing WordPress user host from `%` to `localhost` in the database.